# How to find details like whether the mounted filesystem is read only or read-write with details of status related to the disk health?

Tags: mount, partitioning, ext4, mountpoint

How to find details like whether the mounted file-system is read only or read-write?

In addition to it how to find details of the hard disk or partition health status without affecting the data of that mounted disk or partition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command `mount` will list all mounted partitions and will indicate whether they are mounted read only (ro) or read-write (rw).

There is no way to tell whether a filesystem is "healty" while mounted in a normal read-write mode. To determine whether a filesystem is healthy you need to use `fsck` (or a similar tool) and these require either unmounted filesystems or filesystems mounter read-only.

I guess you could look in the kernel log using command `dmesg` and look for messages like "journal replayed" - they will indicate that the filesystem has been mounted dirty.

Answer (score 1):

The file `/proc/mounts` contains the neccessary information.

For instance, there I have an entry for my jump drive

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/xieerqi/Lexar vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Coma separated list of options and specifically`rw` indicates that this is read-write mounted filesystem. For read-only it would say `ro`

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful and answers first part of my question. can you please also let me know a command or something similar which will help me check if the hard disk partition or for that instance hard disk itself is healthy or not without un-mounting and endangering the data on it.

Comment: I don't know of disk-testing tools that much. I do know of `fsck` , however it's recommended not to use it on a mounted partition. Thus , I suggest you boot from a live cd or usb for Ubuntu, and run it through there, without mounting the actual hard drive. Perhaps another user might answer your question in more detail than I am, @Fabby

Comment: Thanks! No problem at least you tried, so I appreciate it. I hope @Fabby can solve it :)

Answer (score 1):

you'll need a combination of tools, which I believe are bundled in the package smartmontools. [This links](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958057&s=0aa147b8ad8d0dcfd6526702dd55e090&p=11844182#post11844182) holds a fairly nice plan.

> Your first step should be to evaluate the SMART report of each drive
>   using smartctl. `smartctl -a /dev/sdX` assuming a standard SATA
>   controller, with X being the actual drive identifier
>
> Your second step should be an extended drive self-test, smartctl is
>   the way to go here as well: `smartctl --test=long /dev/sdX` and after
>   the test time has passed (between 60 and 240 minutes for most drives),
>   read the results with the command in step 1.
>
> Your third step should be a drive conveyance test, if supported by
>   your drive. You get an error from the following command if it is not
>   supported: `smartctl --test=conveyance /dev/sdX`. Results: see step 1.
>
> Up to this point, simply writing the whole drive would have been a bad
>   idea, since bad sector remappings are done during write operations. In
>   other words, the evidence of the drive failure might have been covered
>   up.
>
> Assuming that all steps above fail to find a problem, you should now
>   use "badblocks" to scan your drives for write errors:
>
> ```
> badblocks -nvs /dev/sdX
> ```
>
> The above is a nondestructive test, use -wvs is the destructive
>   alternative, may be a bit faster.

The ones I pay attention to on my laptop (with SSD drive, different disks have different S.M.A.R.T. tests)

```
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct
183 Runtime_Bad_Block
184 End-to-End_Error 
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator
```

Especially the first indicator is nice, as it tells you how many bad sectors/blocks have been remapped on the disk.